# device open failed error when trying to start multiple camera1394 nodes

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get images from three firewire cameras. I can open each camera when running a single camera1394 node.

Launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="fisheye_camera" cwd="node" respawn="false" output="screen" >
        <param name="guid" type="string" value="000a470104069253" />
        <param name="video_mode" type="string" value="format7_mode0" />
        <param name="format7_color_coding" type="string" value="rgb8" />
        <remap from="/camera" to="/fisheye_camera" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I get the following output as expected:

```
process[fisheye_camera-1]: started with pid [7560]
[ INFO] [1320745534.175589661]: Found camera with GUID a470104069253
[ INFO] [1320745534.175965999]: camera model: AVT Marlin F046C
[ INFO] [1320745534.182929881]: Format7 unit size: (4x2), position: (2x2)
[ INFO] [1320745534.183078333]: Format7 region size: (780x580), offset: (0, 0)
[ INFO] [1320745534.204670708]: [000a470104069253] opened: format7_mode0, 15 fps, 400 Mb/s
[ WARN] [1320745534.292570577]: Calibrated image size (0x0) matches neither full Format7 size (780x580)) nor ROI size (780x580)
[ WARN] [1320745534.292964530]: [000a470104069253] calibration does not match video mode (publishing uncalibrated data)
```

When I now try to open a second camera with a similar launch file (different guid), while the first node is still running:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="pantilt_camera" cwd="node" respawn="false" output="screen" >
        <param name="guid" type="string" value="000a47011109a214" />
        <param name="video_mode" type="string" value="format7_mode0" />
        <param name="format7_color_coding" type="string" value="rgb8" />
        <remap from="/camera" to="/pantilt_camera" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I get the following output with error device open failed:

```
process[pantilt_camera-1]: started with pid [8145]
[ INFO] [1320746488.817020075]: Found camera with GUID a470104069253
[ INFO] [1320746488.825803202]: Found camera with GUID a47010f0771b0
[ INFO] [1320746488.835166689]: Found camera with GUID a47011109a214
[ INFO] [1320746488.835387890]: camera model: AVT Stingray F125C
[ INFO] [1320746488.846285059]: Format7 unit size: (4x2), position: (2x2)
[ INFO] [1320746488.846411706]: Format7 region size: (1292x964), offset: (0, 0)
libdc1394 error: juju: Failed to allocate iso resources
[ WARN] [1320746488.859773482]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: Failed to open device!
[ INFO] [1320746488.870530423]: Found camera with GUID a470104069253
[ INFO] [1320746488.878520477]: Found camera with GUID a47010f0771b0
[ INFO] [1320746488.887673071]: Found camera with GUID a47011109a214
[ INFO] [1320746488.887826032]: camera model: AVT Stingray F125C
[ INFO] [1320746488.898584632]: Format7 unit size: (4x2), position: (2x2)
[ INFO] [1320746488.898770278]: Format7 region size: (1292x964), offset: (0, 0)
libdc1394 error: juju: Failed to allocate iso resources
[ WARN] [1320746488.912427925]: [camera] exception opening device (retrying): [Camera1394::open]: Failed to open device!
[ INFO] [1320746488.923146609]: Found camera with GUID a470104069253
[ INFO] [1320746488.931056190]: Found camera with GUID a47010f0771b0
[ INFO] [1320746488.940165987]: Found camera with GUID a47011109a214
[ INFO] [1320746488.940331928]: camera model: AVT Stingray F125C
[ INFO] [1320746488.953041566]: Format7 unit size: (4x2), position: (2x2)
[ INFO] [1320746488.953164625]: Format7 region size: (1292x964), offset: (0, 0)
libdc1394 error: juju: Failed to allocate iso resources
[ERROR] [1320746488.966902795]: [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: Failed to open device!
```

I allways get the same result no matter which camera I open first.

I am using ROS diamondback on Ubuntu 11.04 (kernel 2.6.38-11-generic), camera_drivers stack is version 1.4.2.
The three cameras are connected via a firewire hub.

Can anybody tell me how I can get the camera nodes to work and open my three cameras at the same time?

Thanks, Kai Bublitz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11850/device-open-failed-error-when-trying-to-start-multiple-camera1394-nodes/) by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 357 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "failed to allocate iso resources" messages suggests that your bus is not providing enough bandwidth for both cameras in the chosen video mode.

If you have a 1394b bus, try setting the `iso_speed` parameter to 800 (Mb/s). The default is 400, which would be correct for the older 1394 bus standard.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on 2011-11-08**:
I can not change the iso_speed, 400 seems to be correct, however I can use different video modes with smaller resolution and it works, thanks.